# converting binary to multiple characters

Tags: c, character-encoding, binary, character, ascii

I basically posted this question yesterday, but I'm running into a different type of error. So I'm trying to create a program where the user enters a 12-bit binary hamming code sequence like "100010010001" and it should print out its corresponding ASCII character, which in this case is 'A'.

The problem is it seems to work for single characters like 'A' but if I type the binary sequence 100010010001010110010010010010000011 which represents 'ABC' it prints out random characters unrelated to what should be printed out. I don't understand what's causing this problem?

```
char charToBin(char usersInput[]) {
    char j = 0 ;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 12 ; i++) {
        if((i == 0) || (i == 1) || (i == 3) || (i == 7)){
                continue ;
        } ;
        usersInput[j] = usersInput[i] ;
        j++ ;
    } ;
    char c = strtol(usersInput, (char **)NULL, 2);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try my answer to that question of your yesterday. That solution will work and the first method should be really fast if you trying to break up the array into steps because it is a small array.

Nonetheless, for this code, the main problem that you have with your code is that you are trying to remove 4 indexes from a char array of 12 indexes without doing anything to tell strtol() that. So in your code, you only have to tell strtol() to stop at index 8 by injecting char '\0' at position 8 or the array which would be the 9th char. Also, since you are going to skip index 0 and 1, there is no point starting from index 0 and evaluating whether if it is index 0 or 1. You can start at index 2. Besides that, "i" should be less than 12 in your loop. That is because the last index of a 12 indexes array would be 11, and not 12. Also, j does not need to be a char. That should be an int.

```
char charToBin(char usersInput[]) {
    int j = 0 ;

    for (int i = 2; i < 12 ; i++) {
        if( (i == 3) || (i == 7) ){
                continue ;
        } ;
        usersInput[j] = usersInput[i] ;
        j++ ;
    } ;
    usersInput[8] = '\0';
    char c = strtol(usersInput, (char **)NULL, 2);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must provide more info about your program like fully functional `main()`, example input and outputs, how to call the functions and etc.

But before that i think Same code like this may works for you.

```
p = len of usersInput  / 12
char * charToBin(char usersInput[], int p) {
    char j = 0 ;
    char *c;

    for(int n=0;n<p;n++){

        for (int i = 0; i <= 12 ; i++) {
        if((i == 0) || (i == 1) || (i == 3) || (i == 7)){
                continue ;
        } ;
        usersInput[j+n] = usersInput[i+n] ;
        j++ ;
    } ;

    c[n] = strtol(usersInput, (char **)NULL, 2);

}

    return c;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for() loop should only iterate for 12 times,hence the condition should be i<12 and create a local character array as I did(to_Char[]) of length 9(8+1 for Null at end) and read appropriate bits into it from usersInput[], usersInput[] shouldn't be provided as input to strtol() as its of 32bits in length but our characters are just 8bits in length.

```
char charToBin(char usersInput[]) {
char j = 0;
char to_Char[9];

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    if ((i == 0) || (i == 1) || (i == 3) || (i == 7)) {
        continue;
    };
    to_Char[j] = usersInput[i];
    j++;
};
to_Char[j] = '\0';

char c = strtol(to_Char, (char**)NULL, 2);
return c;
}
```